# jQuery to put image caption in title field

Tags: jquery, attr

I'm a novice coder. I want to hover my mouse over an image, and show information. My images have the 'Caption' field filled in, and I want to grab that data to move into the title or data-tooltip.

I am doing my site using Semplice, so it's a Wordpress CMS where I'm limited in what code I can change. I am able to inject custom CSS (globally and on each page) and JavaScript (globally)

I can successfully display prewritten text on hover like this:

```
jQuery('.semplice-lightbox').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).css('cursor','pointer').attr('title', 'CUSTOM TEXT');
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).css('cursor','auto');
    });
```

And I can successfully get the image captions and display them below the image like this:

```
jQuery('.semplice-lightbox').find('.lightbox-item').wrap('<div>').after(function() {
    return jQuery('<p>').text(jQuery(this).attr('caption'));
});
```

but I'm having trouble understanding how to combine those two things so that I grab the caption and populate another field (like title or data-tooltip) with what I have in my existing caption field.

If it's helpful, here is the data from inspecting the box all this sits in:

```
<a class="semplice-lightbox"><img class="is-content lightbox-item" src="https://my-website.nfshost.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/the-image-filename.jpg" width="1067" height="1600" alt="Alt text" caption="Caption field" data-width="original" data-scaling="no" data-photoswipe-index="0"></a>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I guess `$('.semplice-lightbox')` is a container of the image, right?

Comment: Yep, that's the image container.

Comment: So the `this` here doesn't refer to the image, which means you can't get the `caption` from `this`.

Comment: Why doesn't each image have a `title=""` attribute on it? Why do you need jQuery to do this? Can you post example HTML?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm working in a Wordpress theme CMS (Semplice) so I'm constrained in what I can edit. I can inject CSS and JavaScript to my existing code but otherwise I can't modify anything. I will edit my question with some more text to try and better explain

Comment: (edited to add information @TJBlackman )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement, I combine two functions together and also `remove()` the `<p>` when the mouse is leaving the image.

```js
jQuery('.semplice-lightbox').hover(function() {
  var $this = jQuery(this) // this here refers to .semplice-lightbox
  $this.css('cursor', 'pointer').find('.lightbox-item').wrap('<div>').after(function() {
    var imageCaption = jQuery(this).attr('caption') // this here refers to .lightbox-item
    $this.attr('title', imageCaption)
    return jQuery('<p>').text(imageCaption);
  });
}, function() {
  jQuery(this).css('cursor', 'auto').find('p').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="semplice-lightbox">
  <img class="is-content lightbox-item" src="https://my-website.nfshost.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/the-image-filename.jpg" width="1067" height="1600" alt="Alt text" caption="Caption field" data-width="original" data-scaling="no" data-photoswipe-index="0">
</a>
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to write this up Hikarunomemory. I'll do a bit more modifying and come back with more questions as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As Hikarunomemory mentioned, your `this` might not be referencing the correct DOM element. Fortunately, every event function gets access to an `event` object automatically, so you can use `event.target` to get a reference to the DOM element that triggered the event. Then you can get it's caption, and use it however you want...

```
$('.semplice-lightbox').hover(function(event){
    var caption = $(event.target).attr('caption'); 
    $(event.target).attr('title', caption);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help - and I'm glad to have learned a bit reading this!